# The best tensorflow neural net I got so far for iris dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Compared to my another post [Logistic Regression for non linearly separable data](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/265767/233283) which uses one-layer net, i.e. Logistic Regression to classify the iris data set, this post is to discuss the tensorflow method.

```
iris = load_iris()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    iris.data, iris.target, test_size=0.33, random_state=2021)
y_train=np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=3)
y_test=np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=3)


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, input_dim=4, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(x_train,y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), batch_size=20,epochs=30,verbose=0)


prediction=model.predict(x_train)
length=len(prediction)
y_label=np.argmax(y_train,axis=1)
predict_label=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)

accuracy=np.sum(y_label==predict_label)/length * 100 
print("Accuracy of the dataset",accuracy )


prediction=model.predict(x_test)
length=len(prediction)
y_label=np.argmax(y_test,axis=1)
predict_label=np.argmax(prediction,axis=1)

accuracy=np.sum(y_label==predict_label)/length * 100 
print("Accuracy of the dataset",accuracy )
```

The accuracy is

```
Accuracy of the dataset 99.0
Accuracy of the dataset 94.0
```

I've tried several times, this is the best performance.

I also tried more and less neurons and layers, the one above is the best.

Comment: As I understand from your post (and previous post) you are not looking for a code review, you are looking for a model review. I believe this is not the correct platform for you to look for answers. Consider looking online for [Hyper-parameter Tuning Techniques](https://towardsdatascience.com/hyper-parameter-tuning-techniques-in-deep-learning-4dad592c63c8).